# Does GitAhead support TLS v1.3?

Tags: bitbucket, libgit2, gitahead

[Bitbucket is announcing](https://bitbucket.org/blog/update-to-supported-cipher-suites-in-bitbucket-cloud) an upgrade in Transport Layer Security, effectively on August 3rd.
I've searched github GitAhead's page and also in libgit2 (github and stackoverflow) about TLS 1.3 support but found nothing.

Does anyone knows if GitAhead will work after that? If not, can anyone point me in some direction to look up the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it will already be fully supported. GitAhead uses its own bundled OpenSSL version 1.1.1 in most cases, which has support for TLS v1.3. On macOS it also uses the system SecureTransport, which I expect will also have support on recent versions of the OS.

Comment: Hi @JasonHaslam, thanks for your response! For the sake of completeness: I'm not used to C projects, but I went to gitahead and find what I think is the dependency to OpenSSL 1.1.1 [in here](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/tree/master/dep/openssl) and after that I confirmed that 1.1.1 include support for TLSv1.3 [in here](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/05/04/tlsv1.3/).